# How to change post meta for all products on product add in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, meta, bulk

So I am using woocommerce and am using a plugin called WP-All-Import to import a database of products into my Quickbooks connected e-commerce platform. Now I need to change the meta "_sync_status" to "on" for all products after this is complete. How would I do that for all products as they get added?

Comment: You can do this using Update Query in MYSQL. Or in the product loop by using ADD_META function.

Comment: Hello @VinaySharma i am a relatively new coder, would you be able to help me with the code?

Answer (score 2):

You first need to fetch all of the WooCommerce Products (post type of "product"), loop over each of them, and update the post meta for each. You can run this code by placing it in your `functions.php` in your theme, a file in the `/wp-content/mu-plugins` "must-use" plugins directory, or anonymously using a plugin like WordPress Developer + Console.

```
// args to fetch all products
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
);

// create a custom query
$products = new WP_Query( $args );

// if products were returned...
if ( $products->have_posts() ):
    // loop over them....
    while ( $products->have_posts() ):
        // using the_post() to set up the $post
        $products->the_post();

        // use $post->ID to update the '_sync_status' post meta value
        update_post_meta( $post->ID, '_sync_status', 'on' );
    endwhile; 
endif;
```

Comment: Would I need to hook this into something or can i just place this there?

Comment: If you put it in `/wp-content/mu-plugins/update-meta.php` it will run every time a page is loaded (so add, refresh, delete). You don't need to hook to anything.

Comment: ^ any file in that directory is always executed by WordPress, the "mu" stands for "Must Use"

Answer (score 0):

Thank you its work for me
i can update and add new post meta to my products.

```
// args to fetch all products
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
);
// create a custom query
$products = new WP_Query( $args );
// if products were returned...
if ( $products->have_posts() ):
    // loop over them....
    while ( $products->have_posts() ):
        $products->the_post();
            if (get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'slide_template')=="" || !get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'slide_template')){
                update_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'slide_template', 'default' );
                echo get_the_ID().' do it'.'<br>';
            }
    endwhile;
endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `pre_post_update` hook is called before the post is saved.

If you wish to do this when they get created or updated you can hijack the REQUEST array

```
add_action('pre_post_update', 'before_data_is_saved_function');
function before_data_is_saved_function($post_id) {
  if ($_REQUEST['post_type'] == 'product') {
    $_REQUEST['_sync_status'] = 'on';
  }
}
```

If you only want to do this when they 'get added' use:

```
add_action('pre_post_update', 'before_data_is_saved_function');
function before_data_is_saved_function($post_id) {
  if ($_REQUEST['post_type'] == 'product' && $_REQUEST['publish'] = 'Publish') {
    $_REQUEST['_sync_status'] = 'on';
  }
}
```